# skopeo inspect does not work behind proxy

Tags: docker, docker-registry, openshift-origin, skopeo

I am facing this while installing OKD 3.11.

While the docker login works from command line, skopeo fail to do so. We are using http/https proxy on the server and have configured proxy for docker as well.

```
[root@hostname-ansible01 openshift-ansible]# docker login registry.redhat.io:443 -u user_openshift -p password

Login Succeeded
```

````
[root@hostname-ansible01 openshift-ansible]# skopeo inspect --creds=user_openshift:password docker://registry.redhat.io:443/openshift3/ose-deployer:v3.11

FATA[0000] pinging docker registry returned: Get https://registry.redhat.io:443/v2/: proxyconnect tcp: EOF```
````

Comment: There is [an existing issue](https://github.com/containers/skopeo/issues/178) but it is marked closed and is so meandering that I can't tell what the actual outcome is. Are you certain that `hostname-ansible01` has the `$https_proxy` environment variable set (and not, perhaps, just set in the docker **daemon's** environment)?

Comment: Thanks @mdaniel.......The issue was with my https_proxy. Secondly, I had also configured docker daemon to use proxy, which wasn't necessary as I had configured proxy settings in my inventory file.